# c# custom date format

Tags: c#, timespan, date-format

I would like to have the word "day(s)" displayed in the output.  I've tried putting escape characters in front of just the "-", in front of all the characters and spaces in "days".  Any ideas or pointers.

This is the line I'm working with, totalTimeInRoom is a TimeSpan:

```
totalTimeInRoom.ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");
```

EDIT:
Just tried this, no luck:

```
totalTimeInRoom.ToString(@"dd \"Days(s)\" \- hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've struggled with this before and always ended up "cheating" using String.Format:

```
// extend with minutes, seconds etc. if needed
var text = String.Format ("{0} day(s), {1} hour(s)", totalTimeInRoom.Days, totalTimeInRoom.Hours);
```

Of course, you could make it much more advanced and only show 'days' if there's actually 1 or more days in the timespan and also instead of unconditionally using "day(s)" you can dynamically append an 's' when the number of days is more than 1.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!!! I will except the answer in 8 minutes.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

As explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx), you can use single quote characters to embed a literal string in your custom date format:

```
totalTimeInRoom.ToString("dd' Day(s) 'hh':'mm':'ss");
```

Comment: @Magnus, it does work with single quote characters. See the link in my updated answer.

Comment: I think you need the space after the `(s)` and before the `'` rather than before the `hh`.  e.g. `totalTimeInRoom.ToString("dd' Day(s) 'hh':'mm':'ss")`

Comment: @IndigoDelta, you're absolutely right. Answer updated, thanks for the heads-up :)

Comment: @Magnus, yup, I initially misplaced the space characters.

Comment: This worked great too! Too bad two checks can't be issued.  Thank you @Frédéric

Comment: Turns out i need to count years too.  I tried to add Year(s) 'yy' but no luck,  any ideas?

Comment: @rd42, you have to surround the literal string (including spaces) with single quotes, like, for instance, `yy' Year(s)'`.